# Line breaks in <textarea> input forms submission: Same for all browsers?

Tags: html, forms, textarea, form-processing

Are line breaks sent the same way by all (major) browsers / operating systems?

Or do Windows clients send line breaks as `\r\n` and *nix send them as `\n`?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, they're different for different OSs.

At least HTML tries to compensate for that when preprocessing HTML input:

> U+000D CARRIAGE RETURN (CR) characters and U+000A LINE FEED (LF) characters are treated specially. Any CR characters that are followed by LF characters must be removed, and any CR characters not followed by LF characters must be converted to LF characters. Thus, newlines in HTML DOMs are represented by LF characters, and there are never any CR characters in the input to the tokenization stage.

http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/parsing.html#preprocessing-the-input-stream

Comment: I understand your first sentence. I don't see how your quote about HTML is related though. The form submission is done through HTTP, right? The form-processing, done on the server side, has little to do with HTML.